# Pandas Insert dictionary values in several columns at the last row

Tags: pandas

I am having a problem on adding values on the specified columns.
Please refer to the below codes for your understanding.

[Possible option, but I really don't want to add None values in the empty spaces. ]

```
a3 = '[10:17:47-579318]A3016KR4167N30003007G1 0001189300000240101747570000000000000000 00011925 00011935 00011892 000118920019265002293475210000000000000000002 00012000 00011786'

df_0 = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['time', 'cur_p', 'exec_q', 'inv_t', 'l_lvl1_q', 's_lvl1_q', 'inv_l_q', 'inv_s_q', 's_or_l'])

b0_dic = {'time': a3[:17],
           'cur_p': None,
           'exec_q': None,
           'inv_t': None,
           'l_lvl1_q': a3[57:63],
           's_lvl1_q': a3[139:145],
           'inv_l_q': None,
           'inv_s_q': None,
           's_or_l': None,}   
df_0.loc[len(df_0)] = b0_dic
df_0
```

Since the above code is really useless since it takes so long time with big data sets,

I would like to make it work as below code,

```
data0 = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['time', 'cur_p', 'exec_q', 'inv_t', 
                             'l_lvl1_q', 's_lvl1_q',
                              'inv_l_q', 'inv_s_q', 's_or_l'])
dic = {'time': a3[:17],
       'cur_p': a3[40:48],
       'exec_q': a3[48:54],
       's_or_l': a3[152:153]}
data0.loc[len(data0)] = dic
data0
```

but it gives me a error code as

"ValueError: cannot set a row with mismatched columns"

Please kindly let me know how I could develop the code

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Side note: Putting dictionaries in Pandas dataframes is likely a misuse of Pandas. It's no better (probably worse) than using a list or dictionary of dictionaries.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this :

```
df_0 = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['time', 'cur_p', 'exec_q', 'inv_t', 'l_lvl1_q', 
                               's_lvl1_q', 'inv_l_q', 'inv_s_q', 's_or_l'])

df_0.loc[len(df_0), ['time', 'cur_p', 'exec_q', 's_or_l']] = [a3[:17], 
                                                  a3[40:48], a3[48:54], a3[152:153]]
df_0
```